Computed signals not working in React component
I have simplified the scenario in this code playground:
https://playcode.io/2199837
Basically - I have a count, which increments when I click a button ... but the computed signal never gets updated ... neither in the JSX template nor in the JS code.
Any idea what am I missing?

Did you try useComputed (and maybe useSignal)?  See the example here

@James - I refactored the code to use hooks - https://playcode.io/2200161 - but got the same result :(

You also need useSignals, to make "react work" with signals.  See this doc - and your example working here
